# Why does my cmd show "isComplete": false instead of "isComplete": true?

Tags: api

I am studying this tutorial.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Can you please tell me why my cmd shows "isComplete": false instead of "isComplete": true?

[Correct Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9teJ.png)

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRJFa.png)

Comment: Please post your code over there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.